# Select messages, calculate the votes average and know if an user already have voted it

Tags: mysql, database

I've a table that cointains informations about votes of various messages of a website.
The table is called **votations** and is formed by: **ID, messageID, userID, vote**

I want retrieve all data from "messages" table, calculate the average vote in "votations" table, and know if a specified user (checking userID into "votations" table) already had voted or not. This is the query for retrieve messages and respective votes average

```
select m.*, AVG(votes) as average_valuation from messages m 
left join votations v on v.messageID = m.id 
group by m.id
```

Assuming that i receive userID has POST data, the query should tell me if he already have voted a message, during the LEFT JOIN process. How i can do that?

Comment: Is every combination of (messageID,userID) UNIQUE? If so, why isn't it PRIMARY ?

Comment: Yes it's unique.. should i set as primary?

Comment: Well, it's up to you - but it seems to me that in this instance your surrogate key is redundant.

Comment: In what sense? It not should memorize doubles of messageID+userID, because one user can vote a message at least once

Comment: Do you mean maybe that ID field is useless?

Comment: Yes. or at least it *appears* to be :-)

Comment: But what happens if ID is for exemple 1264, messageID 12 and userID 64? It's a duplicate or database place some "sign" between messageID and userID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try subquery

```
select 

m.*,
(
select count(1) from messages m1
where m1.id=m.id
and m1.userid=@userid
) as VotedAlready,

AVG(votes)
as average_valuation from messages m 
group by m.id
```

something like..

You can also add other query.